# Dependencies are apparently not loading correctly after upgrade to Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails 3 project, which uses Devise for authentication, to a Rails 3.1 mountable Engine. After the upgrade, Devise doesn't seem to be initialized correctly, raising a `NameError`:

```
uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
```

[This issue from 2010](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/532), which hints at incompatibilities when using Devise outside a regular application environment:

> Probably when you are not running it stand-alone, Devise is not being required.

[This more recent issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1229) does get into specifics, however it is not about my actual problem (maybe not yet).

I don't quite understand where its coming from. A lot of my dependencies, like CanCan and Compass, started giving me errors at boot after the upgrade. They were all `method missing`, `uninitialized constant` and the like. I took this as my chance to either eliminate them or replace them with a more modern alternative. Perhaps I shouldn't have.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by explicitly requiring my dependencies before my Engine's module definition.

```
require 'devise'
```

Comment: This is in fact exactly how you have to write most Ruby programs.

Comment: @Justice, I expected Rails to do this for me. Yeah, I'm spoiled. :( Apparently, Engines don't enjoy the magic of a `Bundler.require` behind the scenes.

Comment: If your `.gemspec` declares a dependencies on `devise`, `cancan`, `compass`, etc., then Rubygems and Bundler might do that for you. But Rails won't. If you are writing a library, you absolutely *must* in all cases declare your dependencies in your `.gemspec` and you absolutely *must* `require` your dependencies before you use them.